# Git mirror without forced pushes

Tags: git

Is it possible somehow to set up a git repository that works as a usual --mirror for pulling into it, but without forcing when pushing *from* it to another repo?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/276079/disable-specific-git-commands-in-a-particular-repository - Might work for you?

Comment: What is --mirror pushing that you want to push? If you are looking for tags and remotes you should be able to push those with a refspec.

Answer (score 4):

You can just add --no-force to disable the forcing behavior like so:

```
git push --mirror --no-force
```

This will disable non-fast-forward updates (tested with git 1.8.0.2).

Comment: Not seeing this behavior in `1.8.4` nor is `--no-force` documented in the man page for `git-push`. Additionally, there are no mentions of the removal of a `--no-force` option in the release notes between `1.8.0.2` and `1.8.4`.

Comment: Interestingly, the --no-force option has no effect if the remote has the "mirror" option set to true in the local config. Once I removed the "mirror" option from the config and set `--mirror` from the command line as shown above, everything worked as advertised. My git version is `1.8.4`.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to do a git push --mirror that will fail if a non-fast forward update is required.

A git push --mirror should fail if the upstream repo has its config set to `receive.denyNonFastForwards true`:

[`git config` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

```
receive.denyNonFastForwards
```

> If set to `true`, `git-receive-pack` will deny a ref update which is not a fast-forward.
>   Use this to prevent such an update via a push, **even if that push is forced**.
>   This configuration variable is set when initializing a shared repository.

That means you wouldn"t have to "reproduce what `--mirror`" does: you could simply use it, and still have that push fail if any non-fastforward merge is involved.

Comment: That's a good idea; unfortunately, I want to push to github in that way, which doesn't support this.

Comment: @miracle2k it can, if you ask GitHub support to protect your repo that way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there maybe a way to reproduce what --mirror does with other options?

Some of what mirror does can be performed using a number of pushes:

```
git push <remote> --all  # push all branches
git push <remote> --tags # push all tags
git push <remote> refs/remotes/* #push the remote refs
```